# Microsoft family features asks to verify account even though account removed from family

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, parental-controls

**Summary:** 
"Windows Family Features" is blocking access to Google Chrome on my child's Windows 10 machine even after removing child's account from Windows Family.

**Detail:**
My son is the local administrator on his Windows 10 machine.  I moved his account across to a Microsoft Account, then I created a Microsoft Family account and added him to it as a child.  A few days later I removed him from the Microsoft Family account.  There are now no children in the Microsoft Family account.

Next he downloaded Google Chrome on the machine. When he tries to start it he gets this message:

"Ask for permission
You'll need to ask an adult in your family if you can use:
Google Chrome"

When he clicks "Ask by email", the next dialog is

"Something went wrong
We're working on it - try again in a little bit.
Trace ID: od7AXEXv+kicfaH4.9.1"

I switched him back to a Local Account on his machine.

Now when he tries to start Google Chrome, he gets this Microsoft family features dialog:

"Verify your Microsoft Account
Make sure your Microsoft account is verified before you ask your parent for permission"

When he clicks the "Verify" button he gets this dialog:
"Did you mean to switch applications?
Microsoft family features is trying to open Microsoft family features"

When he clicks "yes" he gets this dialog:
"Verify your account to continue using Microsoft family features"

...with only a Verify button, which does nothing.

I've seen several similar posts in other fora but no answers.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and been able to fix it without wiping the machine clean or creating a new account?

Comment: You tried to apply Family Safety to an administrator account? That's probably what started this - I would honestly recommend creating a new account and starting over. Secondly, Family Safety is notoriously easy to bypass. Anyone who knows how to do a little system tweaking, even without admin rights, can bypass Family Safety. I would forget about Family Safety and use Group Policy instead.

Comment: Thanks very much for the tip @InterLinked. Yes I did apply Family Safety to an administrator account and am now heartily wishing I hadn't (or that I had bought the boy a Mac instead).  What a festival of fail Family Safety is.  In any case, thanks again.